# Fortran Segmentation fault in variable memory allocation

Tags: fortran, g77

I am new to Fortran and I'm trying to get someone else's code running for larger input. I keep getting a segmentation fault in this area of the code, which (surprise, surprise!!) is dependent on the size of the input. I sent my debug output to a file and flushed after every write so I'm sure it's here and not somewhere else.

```
  integer    npoints, nv1(maxstrucs),ind1,ind2,window
  integer*2  smapall
  real*8     xre(0:maxres),xrp(0:maxres)
  real*8     xse(3,0:maxres),xsp(3,0:maxres)
  real*8     xm(3,3,0:maxres)
  real*8     rms2_fast3, urms
  real*8     xp(3,maxres),xe(3,maxres)

  real       smap,v1
  common /vectors/ v1(maxstrucs,maxres,3)
  common/allall/ smap(maxres,maxres),smapall(numcol,maxres,maxres),
 &     nstrucs
```

maxstrucs is 500, maxres is 150 and numcol is 124750.
I know there is a problem with common fields but I'm compiling using the flag -mcmodel=medium

For reference the compiling statement is

```
g77  -mcmodel=medium -fno-automatic -ffixed-line-length-none -c -o mmult.o mmult.fr code here
```

I've also set the stack size to be unlimited with

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

I have a server with 94Gbs of RAM free. So in theory it should work, unless there is a limit of some sort that I don't know about. Please help

Comment: I suggest trying gfortran.  g77 is obsolete.  With 94 GBs of RAM your server must be 64 bit.  You shouldn't have to worry about the memory model stuff.   Compile with gfortran for a 64-bit executable.

Comment: with gfortran consider using `-fcheck=bounds`.